# Iterating over arrays in cython, is list faster than np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, cython

TLDR: in cython, why (or when?) is iterating over a numpy array faster than iterating over a python list?

Generally: 
I've used Cython before and was able to get tremendous speed ups over naive python impl', 
However, figuring out what exactly needs to be done seems non-trivial.

Consider the following 3 implementations of a sum() function.
They reside in a cython file called 'cy' (obviously, there's np.sum(), but that's besides my point..)

Naive python:

```
def sum_naive(A):
   s = 0
   for a in A:
       s += a
   return s
```

Cython with a function that expects a python list:

```
def sum_list(A):
    cdef unsigned long s = 0
    for a in A:
        s += a
    return s
```

Cython with a function that expects a numpy array.

```
def sum_np(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] A):
    cdef unsigned long s = 0
    for a in A:
        s += a
    return s
```

I would expect that in terms of running time, **sum_np < sum_list < sum_naive**, however, the following script demonstrates to the contrary (for completeness, I added np.sum() )

```
N = 1000000
v_np = np.array(range(N))
v_list = range(N)

%timeit cy.sum_naive(v_list)
%timeit cy.sum_naive(v_np)
%timeit cy.sum_list(v_list)
%timeit cy.sum_np(v_np)
%timeit v_np.sum()
```

with results:

```
In [18]: %timeit cyMatching.sum_naive(v_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit cyMatching.sum_naive(v_np)
1 loops, best of 3: 389 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit cyMatching.sum_list(v_list)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.9 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit cyMatching.sum_np(v_np)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop

In [22]: %timeit v_np.sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 659 us per loop
```

What's going on? 
Why is cython+numpy slow?

P.S.
I do use
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False

Comment: I don't know if cython can speed up a `for a in A` type loop for an array, maybe typing `a` would do the trick. I believe though that the right (or at least more usual) way of speeding that up is something like: `cdef int j; for j in range(len(A)): s += A[j]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a better way to implement this in cython that at least on my machine beats `np.sum` because it avoids type checking and other things that numpy normally has to do when dealing with an arbitrary array:

```
#cython.wraparound=False
#cython.boundscheck=False
cimport numpy as np

def sum_np(np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] A):
    cdef unsigned long s = 0
    for a in A:
        s += a
    return s

def sum_np2(np.int64_t[::1] A):
    cdef:
        unsigned long s = 0
        size_t k

    for k in range(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[k]

    return s
```

And then the timings:

```
N = 1000000
v_np = np.array(range(N))
v_list = range(N)
```

---

```
%timeit sum(v_list)
%timeit sum_naive(v_list)
%timeit np.sum(v_np)
%timeit sum_np(v_np)
%timeit sum_np2(v_np)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 64.9 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.7 s per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop
```

You don't want to iterate over the numpy array via the Python style, but rather access elements using indexing as that it can be translated into pure C, rather than relying on the Python API.

Comment: Does doing `[::1]` have any tangible benefit over `[:]` for 1D arrays?

Comment: I took back my earlier comment. I'm not sure why I got such an improvement, but its not reproducible. Now I get about 650us vs 621us. Thanks Josh! (and +1 for the size_t)

Comment: `[::1]` denotes that the memory is contiguous along that dimension and does appear to make a small difference for this example on my machine.

Comment: It decreases the flexibility of the method though because you can no longer pass a strided slice to it like `sum_np2(v_np[::3])` without getting an error saying that the array is not laid out in a contiguous block in memory.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>`a` is untyped and thus there will be lots of conversions from Python to C types and back. These can be slow.</strike>

JoshAdel correctly pointed out that instead of iterating though, you should iterate over a range. Cython will convert the indexing to C, which is fast.

---

Using `cython -a myfile.pyx` will highlight these sorts of things for you; you want all of your loop logic to be white for maximum speed.

PS: Note that `np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1]` is outdated and has been deprecated in favour of the faster and more general `long[:]`.